# Magento 2: InvalidArgumentException There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace

Tags: magento2.2.2, cli, bin-magento

I have facing issue while run command. I can't use any bin/cli commands in magento 2.

I keep getting below generic error messages.

**Error:** InvalidArgumentException There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.

Comment: Try checking if you have proper permission to execute the commands

Comment: i've set the permissions to 0777. This is just localhost